# Characterization of definite positive matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

We can define a positive definite matrix $A\in M(n\times n)$ as the symmetric matrix where $X^tAX\gt 0$ for every column vector $X\ne 0$ in $n$ coordinates.

Suppose $A$ is symmetric, I would like to prove:

> $A$ is positive definite $\Leftrightarrow$ all its eigenvalues are
>   positive.

I know how to prove the $(\Rightarrow)$ part, I couldn't prove the converse.

I need help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I presume you meant to use $X$ instead if $Y$ above. There is no matrix for which the $>0$ statement can hold.

Comment: @copper.hat yes, thanks for the remark

Answer (score 2):

If it symmetric it is unitarily diagonalisable, that is $A=U \Lambda U^T$, where $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$.

Then $\langle x, A x \rangle = \langle x, U \Lambda U^T x \rangle = \langle U^T x, \Lambda (U^T x \rangle) = \sum_k \lambda_k [U^T x]_k^2 \ge  \lambda_\min \|x\|^2$,
where $\lambda_\min = \min(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n) > 0$.

**Alternatively**:
Look at $\min_{\|x\|^2=1} \langle x, A x \rangle$. Since the unit vectors are compact a minimum exists. The gradient of the constraint is non-zero so we can use Lagrange multipliers. This gives
$Ax+\mu x = 0$ at an extremum. In particular, any extremising $x$ must be a unit eigenvector, and so the corresponding value $\langle x, A x \rangle = \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the corresponding eigenvalue. Since
$\lambda \ge \lambda_\min > 0$, we are finished.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. If the "$\Longrightarrow$" part, use the fact that $X^TAX>0$, for $X=X_j$, the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_j$.

Comment: Yes, that's how I proved ($\Rightarrow$) part.